# How can i solve $x\sin^2(x) + 5x\sin(x) + 4 = 0 $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, transcendental-equations

If I have an equation such as
$$
x\sin^2(x) + 5x\sin(x) + 4 = 0 
$$
with trigonometric functions, how can I solve it?

Comment: You probably can't.  Did this equation come from a problem you care about, or did you just make it up?

Comment: This would be simpler to solve in the form $x^2\sin^2(x) + 5x\sin(x) + 4 = 0$.

Comment: You can find (approximate) numerical solutions by standard numerical methods, such as Newton's method.  Here it is in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+x+sin%5Bx%5D%5E2+%2B+5+x+sin%5Bx%5D+%2B+4+%3D+0). "Closed-form" solutions probably don't exist.

Comment: I made it up. When I wrote this I had no idea about transcendental equations.

Answer (score 3):

Your equation is a quadratic in $\sin(x)$ with coefficients $x$, $5x$, and $4$. We can use the quadratic formula:

\begin{align}
\sin(x) \, &= \, \displaystyle\frac{-5x \pm \sqrt{25x^2-16x}}{2x}\\\\
\sin(x) \, &= \, \displaystyle\frac{-5x \pm \sqrt{x^2\left(25-\displaystyle\frac{16}{x}\right)}}{2x}\\\\
\sin(x) \, &= \, \displaystyle\frac{-5 \pm \sqrt{25-\displaystyle\frac{16}{x}}}{2}\\
\end{align}

Note that the negative case of the right-hand-side expression will never exceed $-5/2$, and so cannot equal an output of $\sin(x)$. So solutions must satisfy $$\sin(x) \, = \, \displaystyle\frac{-5 + \sqrt{25-\displaystyle\frac{16}{x}}}{2}$$

This doesn't lead to a closed form solution, but [graphing the left-hand-side and the right-hand-side](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rh3o28tfpb) shows us the solution set and that it is infinite:

[image]

If you're interested in a specific solution for some application, you may find a nearby point via this graph, then use numerical methods to efficiently obtain arbitrary precision.

Answer (score 0):

Solving the quadratic equation we have

$$ 2x\sin(x)+ 5x\mp \sqrt{25x^2-16x}=0$$

There are two separate transcendental equations to be solved numerically.